# Finding distance between two points and land cover in %?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, land-cover

I am trying to use ArCGIS.

I was using digimap to work out a 2km buffer from a sample point, I managed to do that and saved the file. I also saw some land cover types on the left hand side of [Digimap](http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/) under map content: showing neutral grassland, improved grassland etc color coded. I am trying to workout the landcover type percentage in that 2km buffer zone but I cannot do that on Digimap. When I upload it onto ArcGIS, I can open it by logging online, but I am completely lost from there! Please can someone show me how to do this?

Also I am trying to work out the distance between two points ( I have grid references ) on arcGis so that I can display a picture.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Here you seem to be asking two questions (there should be only one asked per question) and for whichever one you choose we will need more details about what you have tried and precisely where you are stuck.